# How to define a drawable be above a paint?

Tags: java, android, draw, seekbar

I have a custom Seekbar, where i draw a rectangles. But after that, thumb (seekbar controller) became under the paint. How i can make my thumb above this paint?

Here is a painting code:

```
    rectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    rectPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
    rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    ...
    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(paddingLeft+segmentS, paddingTop+5, paddingLeft+segmentE, hh+paddingTop-5 , rectPaint);
     }
```

My thumb is a shape dravable

Comment: Sry, I can't add a picture, case i'm just registred

Comment: try calling super after your stuff

Comment: noop, in that case onDraw stuff doesn't work at all

Comment: so use a custom Drawable class and set it as a background (`View#setBackground`)

Comment: BTW i dont know what you did but that snippet just works: http://codeshare.io/HteK1

Comment: ok, it works, i just didn't see it under seekbar background. Can you explain, why it depends by place, where i call super, and how i can control z position of paint?

Comment: its simple super draws your Seekbar progress and thumb Drawable,  paint has no position

Comment: BTW bis: seekbar's background is drawn below your drawing code: see modified code snippet where i set yellow background and draw red rectangle above it

Comment: Thank you so much! I gonna figure it out totally)